# Layman's explanation of environment variables and OS shells

Tags: macos, npm, environment-variables, fish

Web development is new to me and I'm trying to grasp the meaning and usage of environment variables once and for all. In my research the most simple explanation I've come across is that it is comparable to 'configuration settings'.

Through the terminal I've been exploring what feels like the computer's innards by typing `printenv` *etc etc.*

But I'm still not sure when it is necessary to set up env var. For example, I use `fish` as my shell. Often when I try to do an `npm install` it seems like the package didn't take. Here is a recent example:

```
user@iMac-van-user ~/P/v/v/public_html> npm install -g modernizr
/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.4.0/bin/modernizr -> /usr/local/Cellar/node/10.4.0/lib/node_modules/modernizr/bin/modernizr
+ modernizr@3.6.0
updated 1 package in 2.316s
user@iMac-van-user ~/P/v/v/public_html> modernizr
```

When I try to use `modernizr` as a command `fish` will tell me the `modernizr` is an unknown command and the color remains red. Valid commands show up in white in fish. Thus I have a suspicion that `modernizr` will only be available and valid once I've set up the configs. I've had this happen many times with various attempts to install package managers and things like `composer`, `vue-cli`, etc. My failures to get it working boils down to my meager knowledge of environment variables and what they do, I think.

This is from the documentation on the `modernizr` site: `modernizr -c modernizr-config.json`

> Note that you will need to give the command line config the file path
>   to the configuration you downloaded from the site. In the above
>   example, we are running the modernizr command from the same folder
>   that we downloaded the modernizr-config.json file to.

What does the sentence: *"Note that you will need to give the command line config the file path to the configuration you downloaded from the site"* imply?  I copied the file into my project folder but there is no change.

Is there is someone that can explain the following to me in layman's terms, so like you would to a 5 year old, it would be great:

1. use of environment variables
2. setting up configs - why, where and how (I've done it once through VIM)
3. how to know when to set up environment variables

Thank you in advance.
Developing on macOS 10.

Comment: are you using something like nvm? when you do `which node` on the terminal what do you get?

Comment: @FabioAntunes when I type `which node` I get `/usr/local/bin/node`. I am not familiar with nvm

Comment: how did you install node?

Comment: @FabioAntunes It was months ago that I installed it but I did it with the Node.js installer I downloaded through the official node website https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: What about npm, when you do `which npm` what do you get. It seems somehow your npm binaries are not being added to your $PATH

Comment: Also try running `npm ls -g --depth=0` and see if all the global packages have their binaries available.

Comment: @FabioAntunes Thank you for your help sofar. I've run the commands as advised by you and this is what comes out of it: 
`usr@iMac-van- usr ~> which npm
/usr/local/bin/npm
 usr@iMac-van- usr ~> npm ls -g --depth=0
/usr/local/Cellar/node/10.4.0/lib
├── modernizr@3.6.0
├── nodemon@1.17.5
└── sass-watch@0.1.0`

Comment: @FabioAntunes I came across this link:
[https://www.npmjs.com/package/add-local-binaries-to-path] where they recommend doing `npm i -g add-local-binaries-to-path` so as to 
make locally-installed node modules executable by name by adding ./node_modules/.bin to the $PATH. 
Will this be useful for me?

Comment: I think it has something to do with your node instalation and npm not adding the npm bin folder to your $PATH. Try reinstalling node or try doing what people suggest on this ticket https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4851

Comment: can you do a `ls -la /usr/local/share/npm/bin`? You might need to add that path to your $PATH

Comment: @FabioAntunes When I do `ls -la /usr/local/share/npm/bin` it says no such file or directory. How do add it to my $PATH? According to the way you suggested in your second last comment?